# The importance of sugar plantations

Tags: 19th-century

Plantations in the West Indies like coffee, sugar, tobacco and cotton was important in the 16,17,18 and 19th century and the colonial powers made a lot of profit from them. In the late 19th century the American and Caribbean plantations some how lost their importance. Why exactly is that? Is it because the colonial powers started new colonies other parts of the world and therefore started new sugar, coffee and tobacco import from there ?

Comment: This is a very general question. - it ranges over 400 years and the global economy.  Any answer to a question that broad is going to be relatively meaningless.  If you refine the question down to a single century then it might be possible to answer.  The rise and fall of slavery. Rise of industrialization.  the evolution of mercantilism to capitalism. Changes in global trade patterns, etc.

Comment: Suggest narrowing down to sugar - quite well-documented and answerable.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace  4 centuries are the introduction. the question is about the end of the 19th centuries. Not so narrow at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about four different commodities:

Cotton: the West Indies was never an important source of cotton. Currently Barbados has a grand total of 214 acres of cotton under cultivation. That would be the tiniest of a one family farm in the United States. In 1902 there were 1200 acres under cultivation in Barbados, a microscopic amount. In 1800 there were *hundreds of thousands* of acres of cotton in India and the United States.

Tobacco: same story as cotton, the amount of acreage in the United States has always dwarfed the Caribbean.

Sugar: Sugar grows very well in the Caribbean and so it has always been an important producer and still is. At one time it was the dominant producer of sugar but this changed around 1820 due to the development of beet sugar technology and the abolition of the global slave trade by the British. It is notable that at the same time there was a huge decline in the city of Bristol, which previously had been a very wealthy port due to the sugar trade.

Coffee: Coffee grows in a very wide variety of places so the Caribbean was never a dominant producer, but it does grow well there so at one time the plantations in the Caribbean were big producers of coffee. The decline of the plantations around 1820 due to the abolition of the slave trade caused the production of coffee to decline. Note that places like Columbia and Mexico have much better economies and support structures than the West Indies, so they tend to be able to produce and sell coffee more cheaply. In the Caribbean Puerto Rico has been best able to maintain its coffee industry due to the support from the United States.

Comment: Make  that roughly 10 million acres of cotton cultivation in the *ante-bellum* South; not hundreds of thousands. A measly four townships (at 36 sq. miles each) is nearly 100,000 acres, noting that 1 sq. mile = 640 acres.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens My figure is for the date 1800.

Comment: And you compare that to a 1902 figure in Barbados; clever. "The three classes of Liars comprise: *Liars*; *Damned Liars*; and *Statisticians*."

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Most of the arable land in Barbados has been used for sugar cane historically. I do not know what the cotton acreage was in 1800, but undoubtedly it was a small amount, certainly less than 10,000 acres so the comparison is not unreasonable.

Comment: Why exactly do beet sugar technology have an impact on the sugar export ?

Answer (score 0):

Industrialization made raw material production less valuable compared to the value added in factory production. They lost their importance because they were overtaken by newer, more profitable industries.